# How to install shellcheck 0.7.0 version in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bash, software-installation

How do I install shellcheck 0.7.0 version in Ubuntu 18.04?

When I run `apt-get install shellcheck`, it will not install version 0.7.0 .

Currently it installs only 0.4.6 but vs code I need 0.7.0 as a prerequisite.

Comment: Use `brew` -> "Homebrew on linux" or compile it from source.

Comment: I am new to linux ubuntu can you please elaborate on brew

Comment: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/linuxbrew-wrapper.7.html and https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ provide information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install the precompiled binary directly from their GitHub page.

```
wget -qO- https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/releases/download/v0.7.0/shellcheck-v0.7.0.linux.x86_64.tar.xz | tar -xJf -
cd shellcheck-v0.7.0/
sudo cp shellcheck /usr/local/bin
```

Finally you can check the version.

```
$ shellcheck --version
ShellCheck - shell script analysis tool
version: 0.7.0
license: GNU General Public License, version 3
website: https://www.shellcheck.net
```

https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck#installing-a-pre-compiled-binary

Comment: Thank you. To make it work on my Ubuntu 18.04, I had to do `sudo apt-get remove shellcheck` before and an extra link: `sudo cp shellcheck /usr/bin`

Comment: using your suggestion, I get the error - zsh: exec format error: shellcheck